# Retain chilli powder taste till end of cooking

Tags: spices, chili-peppers, spicy-hot, powder

When I add chilli powder to an Indian curry, and let it lid-closed for next 5-7 minutes, by the time it's cooked, it loses it's taste and the curry becomes bland. What should I do to retain the spice and colour (as even a pinch of Turmeric and 2 spoonful red chilli powder makes the curry yellowish? Why does it become bland??

Comment: What do you mean loses its taste? Are you saying you taste it right after you add it, and then a few minutes later and there's a difference between the two strengths of flavor? Or are you saying you don't taste it straight after but you think it should be spicier?

Answer (score 2):

2 probable causes

1. you did not put enough chili powder.
2. the chili powder is [stale](https://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/are-your-herbs-spices-too-old-heres-check-0169844/).

Some chili powder are not "spicy hot", taste some before adding it to your curry.